# Can't use the sudo command, not in sudoers!

Tags: gnome, sudo, 16.10

I'm using 16.10 Ubuntu Gnome. When I try to use `sudo` in command line, it says that I'm not in the `sudoers` group, and "this incident will be reported".

What should I do?

Comment: Your don't have `root` privileges. to add yourself in `sudoers` you need root password and add yourself in `visudo`.

Comment: how can i log in as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add yourself to the `adm` group in `/etc/group` by editing the file (logged in as root).

If you aren't root (which most people probably aren't), follow these steps: https://askubuntu.com/a/165248/595510.

Comment: how can i log in as root that is the question,i dont know whats my root password,never logged in as root..

Comment: do you use BIOS? (we'll break into the root account temporarily)

Comment: well when i start my pc there is like f2 for BIOS i think

Comment: okay, so hold Shift till GRUB comes up, then press `e` and add the following kernel options: `rdinit=/bin/sh`.

Comment: I dont how to access bios after i log in to my acc(or if there is a possibility to do that)

Comment: i`ve been holding shift for like 1 minute,and nothing appears

Comment: i got it mate,tnx for the help!!

Comment: please approve my answer